# Knockout - date binding, ActionLink binding

Tags: knockout.js

Hi :) Im new to Knockout. I have some problems that I didnt solve, and I think I saw all the possible solutions here in stackoverflow and from the whole web and I just cant figure it out :(

The upper table is without Knockout js , now Im trying to convert it to:

[Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51PJD.png)

The upper tabke code:

```
<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <th>
            Driver ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>

        <th>
            Phone number
        </th>
        <th>
            Work exp. (days)
        </th>
        <th>
            Last vision test
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        string style = "";
        var months = ((DateTime.Today.Year - item.visionTDate.Year) * 12 + (DateTime.Today.Month - item.visionTDate.Month));
        if (months >= 5 && months < 6)
        {
            style = "background-color:#b3b3ff";
        }
        if (months >= 6)
        {
            style = "background-color:#ff6666";
        }

        <tr style="@style">


            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DriverId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tel)
            </td>
            <td>
                @{ var days = ((DateTime.Today - item.startDate).TotalDays);}
                @days

            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.visionTDate)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.DriverId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.DriverId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.DriverId })
            </td>


        </tr>
                    }

</table>
```

The second table code im trying to do with Knockout js:
VIEW

```
<table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Driver Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Phone number</th>
                                <th>Work exp. (days)</th>
                                <th>Last vision test</th>
                                <th>  </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: drivers">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text: DriverId"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: firstName + ' '+ lastName"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: tel"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: startDate"></td>
                                @*<td data-bind="text: moment(visionTDate()).format('L') "></td>*@
                                <td data-bind="text: visionTDate"></td>
                                @*<td>
                                    <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Edit")/' + DriverId() }" >
                                        Edit 
                                    </a> |
                                    <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Details")/' + DriverId() }" >
                                        Details 
                                    </a>|
                                    <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Delete")/' + DriverId() }" >
                                       Delete
                                    </a>
                                </td>*@

                            </tr>
                    </table>
```

VIEW MODEL

```
     <script>
                        var drivers

                        $.getJSON("/Drivers/GetAllDrivers", function (data) {
                            drivers = data
                            ko.applyBindings(drivers)
                        })

                        function GetStyle(date) {
                            var style = "";
                            var months = ((DateTime.Today.Year - date.Year) * 12 + (DateTime.Today.Month - date.Month));
                            if (months >= 5 && months < 6) {
                                style = "background-color:#b3b3ff";
                            }
                            if (months >= 6) {
                                style = "background-color:#ff6666";
                            }
                        }

                    </script>
```

(Some are commented because it just dont work).

So where i stuck?

1. No matter whet ive tried- it just dont show the date as it suposed to. As u can see in the code below, i tried Moment to but nothing seems to happen but all the rows but the first seem to dissapered:
   [Here u can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av8Vg.png)

   2. Im tring to bind it with the MVC action link by the way u can see in the commented code , but here to- it make the rows dissapered like 2^ and the links are unclickable.

3.As u can see the rows in color and the view model code, i need the row will be red if 6 months or more pass since the last vision date , to be blue if 5-6 months has been pass, otherwise in default color. More than this, to convert the work exp date from date to days (number) as i did in the upper table. tried to write a function to do the colors in the view model but it doesnt work too..

thanks

Comment: For the date have you tried it without the parenthesis after visionTDate?  data-bind="text: moment(visionTDate).format('L')"

Comment: yeah ive tried.. doesnt work too.

Comment: Seems to work for me. What does your json look like? https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/2doxormw/